# Is there a way to save the results in a table, dataframe, matrix or an array

Tags: r, playing-cards

Trying to save the results of multiple deals of a shuffled deck in a table. Also, is there a better way to do multiple deals (like a function or a loop)?

I've tried list:

```
# SETUP for a deck is done
cards <- setup(deck)
deal <- cards$deal
shuffle <- cards$shuffle
deal()
#deal works

# Creating a collection of decks
deckr <- function(){
a<- deal()
b<- deal()
c<- deal()
list(a,b,c)
}
deckr()
```

Comment: "Better" how exactly? You could use something like `replicate()` to perform an action multiple times and save it in a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
deals <- list()
for (i in 1:3)
    deals[[i]] <- deal()
```